# LTE, downlink multiple antenna channel estimation with and without Channel State Information (CSI)

Tags: wireless, digital-communications, dsp

In an LTE downlink with CSI at the transmitter, is the radio Tx in the base station and Rx at the user end hardware part of the channel estimation?

example: Tx to Tx and Rx to Rx isolation between different transmit and receive paths in a multiple antenna system

How about  TDD without CSI: is Tx to Tx and Rx to Rx isolation included in calibration?

Comment: sorry, I really don't understand what you mean at all. "closed loop" and "downlink" are two terms that are not compatible. "Downlink" means "signal flows from central thing to far away thing, in one direction"  and "closed loop" means "signal flows to device and back, forming a control loop". So, you'll really have to try and reword what you're asking.

Comment: Downlink: Signal flows from base station to cellular or user end

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I said. That is a *one-way* thing. A *closed loop* is, as the name says, a *two-way* thing. So you can't have "closed loop downlink". That's like a "circular straight line".

Comment: Closed loop: Transmitter receives information about channel from receiver, i.e. Transmitter knows the channel state information

Comment: Open loop: Transmitter does not know the channel state information.

Comment: Ah, a transmitter with CSI.

Comment: At the end the data flows from transmitter to receiver , base station to user end whether in closed or open loop

Answer (score 0):

Since crosstalk is not correlated to the signal you want to receive, it's kind of like noise (or more precisely, interference).

So, yeah, that *can* be part of CSI (but not in the "channel impulse response" sense, but in the "also, SINR" sense).

That SINR estimate might be important for rate adaption and power allocation schemes (e.g. in waterfilling for MIMO).

However, since the crosstalk is something that the handset's designer knows, there's no reason to measure it - it's factory-defined. I don't think I'd call that "calibration" CSI.

Cross-talk estimates are indeed sometimes used in the integrated transceiver ICs for some multicarrier schemes with up- and downlink frequencies with little separation. However, this is kind of done as a countermeasure against analog imperfection, and is of no real relevance to the usage of the transceiver as LTE device – LTE simply sees a higher noise floor in the receiver.

In TDD, the problem typically doesn't arise, due to the fact that it *is* TDD.

Comment: 1-If one needs to separate between 2 streams, antenna-antenna  isolation  (I'll limit the discussion to Rx) becomes part of the channel matrix , the question is does Rx-Rx isolation inside the receiver also become part of channel matrix 2- In TDD channel reciprocity is used and needs to be restored by calibration, the question is what is the scope of the calibration again only in Rx?

Comment: 1-. Well, whatever your receiver observes. So, yes. 2- don't understand that question.

Comment: 2- in TDD on downlink and uplink the channel is supposed to remain the same, so the transmitter does not need an extra overhead information from the receiver to know the channel, since in the reverse direction he indirectly has access to the channel information, so this called "open loop". Channel remaining the same applies however to the path between the antennas, i.e. the wireless path, but the radios on Tx and Rx are not the same so they need to be calibrated to restore reciprocity

Comment: I'd argue that the "open loop" and "closed loop" characterizations aren't *useful*. What matters is whether the transmitter has CSI or not – not how it got that.